# MySQL Design: Seperate Schema or Table Prefixes?

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

I have a hobby project where I am creating my own software that will have different modules.  The idea is to make the modules stackable and can be toggled off and on.  I am using MySQL as the database back-end, and am wondering if it is better to have module-specific tables on their own schema, or if te tables should be prefixed.  For example, let's say I have a systems module and an employees module; would putting all tables related to employees on an employee scheme be better than just prefixing the table names with something like "emp_"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of a moot point for MySQL, because databases and schema are interchangeable in MySQL.  It would be more relevant for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Prefixing table names is usually unnecessary clutter; the table names or the tables you are `JOINing` to should make it obvious what is going on.  There is no performance difference between all-tables-in-one-db vs several dbs; there is a slight syntax diff.

Answer (score 0):

My MySQL the keyword `database` was renamed into `schema` because they are not separated database. You can still have relationships across schemas.

In some ORM such as Laravel Eloquent you can write relationships such as:

```
$company->hasMany(Employee)
```

In this kind of relationship you will have a pivot table named `company_employee`. If you have two separated schemas, where do you want to put your pivot table? On the `company` schema or on the `employee` schema?

Laravel will fail to solve this question and it not trivial to create such relationship across schemas.